# How to parse a downloadable list from a web site?

Tags: java, selenium, parsing, web-scraping

There is a web site with a list `<ul>` (that is loaded when you scroll to the end). In `<ul>` of 1800,000 items `<li>`, need parse all. I use class `Robot` and method `mouseWheel`, but the computer hangs on up to 50,000 more. Сompletion is extremely long.
I use method

```
public void scrollToEnd() {
        robot.mouseWheel(100000);
    }
```

Are there any better solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with Selenium for a long time. mouseWheel() doesn't work in some cases. I use this

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, -10000)");
```

So, you scroll down and check, if your element is visible or clickable, what you need

```
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(webElement)
```

Comment: `mouseWheel` work, but because of the large number of `<li>` browsers hangs. ```((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, -10000)");``` does not scroll <ul>

Comment: The main idea is try to scroll by js code, and after each js execution check state of element. I had some cases, when worked only with js code